# The opposite effect of scratch card for Android. (Anti erase effect of picture)

Tags: android, image, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I make application, where have 2 pictures(layers) and where I can erase some part of foreground image(using tapping and finger painting). To make this, I had used ScratchView library for Android. [Android-WScratchView](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView)

This give opportunity to erase parts of images. But next step - this is "anti erase". I must use my finger to draw, and to restore parts of the image that have been erased.
I dont understand how do it. May be possible change some method of library class and this is will have opportunity to "anti erase". May be I should create special handler for this. 
I had tried done it for a long time, and I hope that you can help me in this. Thanks!